# Is that correct to ask "How many previous owners does it have had"?

Tags: grammar

Is that correct to ask "How many previous owners does it have had?" If I want to know the number of previous owners of something?

Also: "How many previous owners has it had?"

Which one is more common to say?

Comment: The second is common.  The first is quite incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. We use auxiliary *do* (*does*, *did*) only when there isn't any other auxiliary.

*have had* is a perfect, using the the auxiliary *have*, so *How many owners does it have had?* is not grammatical. *How many owners has it had?* is the grammatical form.

Comment: *How many previous owners **did** it have?* Is also fine.

Comment: Indeed. As is often the case, you can choose a simple past or a perfect, depending on whether you are choosing to think of it as a completed set of events or a continuing set of events.